# multiple v-checkbox after option remove multiple select not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I will try to simplify my explanation.

https://codepen.io/jordan_gio/pen/QeRNZr

```
Check it out.
```

**When It works :** Don't click Remove. Try to select one or more items. It works right?

**When it doesn't work:** Now try to remove the first one(Remove button after the first item). Then try to select checkboxes once again. After removal, both of them get selected and then I can't choose multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an index of the item as the key and then transform the array. It is not a good idea. To solve your problem use `e` as a `:key` instead of `index`.

```
<li v-for="e in options">
  <v-checkbox
    :key="e"
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, can I have an array as i have for v-model or should I have different v-models for each one of checkbox and they will be true or false

Comment: It depends on the situation. For independent checkboxes better to use multiple models. But for collections, it better to use an array